# Autofill input with another input values

Tags: javascript, autofill

I need to autofill an input field with the values of another input fields. So far I have this:

```
$("#field1, #field2").keyup(function(){
    $("#result").val(this.value);
});

<input type="text" id="field1" name="field1" value="" >
<input type="text" id="field2" name="field2" value="" >

//* to be filled with the values of the inputs above *// 
<input type="text" id="result" name="resut" value="">
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: javascript, but if there's another way, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: So you want one input to be filled with two inputs ? I don't get what you are expecting here.

Comment: Yes! I need one input to be filled with two input values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about

```
$("#field1, #field2").keyup(function(){
    update();
});

function update() {
  $("#result").val($('#field1').val() + " " + $('#field2').val());
}
```

```js
$("#field1, #field2").keyup(function(){
    update();
});

function update() {
  $("#result").val($('#field1').val() + " " + $('#field2').val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="field1" name="field1" value="" >
<input type="text" id="field2" name="field2" value="" >
<br>
<input type="text" id="result" name="resut" value="">
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked! You help making this site awesome!

Comment: Thank Ninetainedo.
name mistake (name="result").

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#field1, #field2").keyup(function(){
    update();
});

function update() {
  $("#result").val($('#field1').val() + " " + $('#field2').val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="field1" name="field1" value="" >
<input type="text" id="field2" name="field2" value="" >
<br>
<input type="text" id="result" name="resut" value="">
```

```js
$("#field1, #field2").keyup(function(){
    update();
});

function update() {
  var a = $('#field1').val();
  var b = $('#field2').val();

  $("#result").val('x');
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="field1" name="field1" value="" >
<input type="text" id="field2" name="field2" value="" >
<br>
<input type="text" id="result" name="resut" value="">
```